# How to dynamically reuse resolvers in Apollo?

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

Say I have the following query:

```js
// queries.js

const GET_FOO = gql`
  query Foo {
    foo {
      id
      bar
      baz @client
      qux @client
    }
  }
`
```

And the following resolvers:

```
// resolvers.js

export default {
  Foo: {
    baz: root => computeBaz(),
    qux: root => computeQux(root.baz),
  }
}
```

`root.baz` is undefined.

Is it possible to reuse `baz` in computing `qux`? I couldn't find a solution for this in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Here are all the params passed to a resolver:

```
fieldName: (obj, args, context, info) => result;
```

We can use the context to pass data between resolvers:

```js
export default {
  Foo: {
    baz: (root, _args, context) => {
      context.baz = computeBaz()
      return context.baz;
    },
    qux: (root, _args, context) => {
      return computeQux(context.baz);
    }
  }
}
```

Also see the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/local-state-management/) on local state.

Comment: This link doesnt work, can you please provide another link. I can't seem to use the context argument correctly.